# Is there any reason to NOT take deliveries of cars in GT5?

Tags: gran-turismo-5

GT5 gives you the option to not take deliveries of cars - are there any good reasons for that or is it just as good to take deliveries of everything and sell the clunkers?

Comment: Don't sell them, keep them. Eventually you get 1000 cars trophy

Answer (score 8):

I think the reason they've implemented the "Delivery" system is that they're keen for you to have at least one look at all the cars you receive. The whole GT Life mode seems geared towards giving the player an experience of a range of cars throughout history, so they don't want you to have cars just appear in your garage that you never notice.

So no, I don't think there is any reason to refuse delivery of a car.

Comment: I tend to agree with you - which is the basis for the question. Why would game maker put in a feature they don't want you to use (as in not take delivery).  Is there anything you can do with a ticket that you can't do with a delivered car?

Comment: @Hotei - Even if you take the delivery of all the cars the feature is not 'unused'. By making you actively trade a ticket for a car they ensure that cars don't just appear in your garage and that you are in control of which cars go in your garage or not.